# Hibernate & javaassist proxy / lazy initialization causing errors with reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, proxy, javassist

I'm using Hibernate 4 and am trying to use reflection to access a field from an entity just loaded from the DB.  However, retrieving the field value via reflection returns a value of null even though the entity's field actually has a value.

After doing a little debugging, I see that the entity retrieved is a javassist proxy to the entity.  I am presuming the problem is due to lazy loading of the entity, but am not sure how to fix the problem.

```
@Entity
public class User
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String username;
  private String password;

  @Version
  @Column(name="version")
  private Integer version;
}


public User updateUser(long userId, User user) {
    // first need to find the user in the db
    User u = checkNotNull( userRepository.findOne(userId) );

    // get the version field
    Field field = User.class.getDeclaredField("version");

    // check that the versions of the two objects match
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    Object targetVersion = checkNotNull( ReflectionUtils.getField(field, u) );

    return u;
}
```

In the debugger, I see that `u` is actually of type `class com.ia.domain.User_$$_jvst8cf_3` and not `com.ia.domain.User`.  If I drill-down on the var and inspect the `version` field, it is listed as `null`.  However `u.getVersion()` will retrieve a proper value.

Is there anyway to get the value via reflection?  Do I have to handle the case of it being a proxy object differently?  I would rather not need to know about the existence of a proxy object if possible, and just treat the retrieved object as a `User` object which it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used PropertyUtilsBean (apache commons beanutils) to retrieve the field value:

```
PropertyUtilsBean beanUtil = new PropertyUtilsBean();
beanUtil.getProperty(entity, propertyName);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the underlying class from the proxy by doing this:

```
if (user instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    user = (User) ((HibernateProxy) user).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
}
```

Note that if the object has not been initialized by hibernate (a lazily loaded association, for instance), you need to first initialize it:

```
Hibernate.initialize(entity);
```

Comment: My issue with this approach is that I am using JPA and consequently trying to make it provider agnostic.  By using specific Hibernate methods, I am tying myself directly into using Hibernate as a JPA provider which I do not want to do.  Any ideas if there is a way to do this that isn't Hibernate specific?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Hibernate.getClass(user)